# Replacing {phrase} with <a href="/phrase">phrase</a> in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to search and replace any occurrence of {phrase} with with `<a href="/phrase">phrase</a>` using rails (erb.html file). Multiple phrases will need to be substituted, and the phrases aren't known in advance.

Full Example:

`Hi {guys}, I really like {ruby on rails}`

Needs to become

`Hi <a href="/guys">guys</a>, <a href="/ruby on rails">ruby on rails</a>`

This is for a user-generated content site ([GMT](http://givemetruth.com/))

Comment: I am not sure about Ruby... but will regex do? It is simple ... match this `{([a-zA-Z]+)}`

Comment: Can't see why not, I will try that, thank you.

Comment: please recheck your example. i think you missed `"` at the end of `guys`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's simple regexp, just use

```
your_string.gsub(/{(.*?)}/, '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>')
```

Example:

```
"{aaa} is not {bbb} you know".gsub(/{(.*?)}/, '<a href="/\\1">\\1</a>')
```

will produce

```
<a href="/aaa">aaa</a> is not <a href="/bbb">bbb</a> you know
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using gsub

```
irb(main):001:0> str = " I have written this phrase statement, I want to replace occurences of all phrase with other statement"
=> " I have written this phrase statement, I want to replace occurences of all phrase with other statement"
irb(main):002:0> str.gsub("phrase",'<a href="/phrase">phrase</a>')
=> " I have written this <a href=\"/phrase\">phrase</a> statement, I want to replace occurences of all <a href=\"/phrase\">phrase</a> with other statement"
```

Comment: I won't know "phrase" in advance, it's user generated content I'm working with.

Comment: you could do str.gsub(variable, '<a href="' + variable + '">' +variable + '</a>')

Comment: So, instead of passing phrase as a string pass variable there.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this will be to use a Markdown output engine ([Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) being one of the most robust)

You'd have to create a [custom renderer](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-you-can-even-cook-your-own):

```
#lib/custom_renderer.rb
class AutoLinks < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def auto_link(phrase) #-> will need to search through content. Can research further
    link_to phrase, "/#{phrase}"
  end
end

#controller
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(AutoLinks, auto_link: "ruby on rails")
```

Comment: I am actually using Redcarpet on this application already, will explore this option if the gsub answer doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a helper in your erb. For example:

**tag_helper.rb:**

```
module TagHelper
  def atag(phrase)
    "<a href='/#{phrase}'>#{phrase}</a>"
  end
end
```

**some.html.erb:**

```
<%= atag('guys')%>
```